# How to custom xjc generated enum and field name?

Tags: java, json, xml, enums, jaxb

Here is the question, our contract is XSD file. Lately we want it to support `Json`.But there is some tricky problem we have to solve. When I define xsd like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="SomeType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="SomeSelfDefineType" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The generated code is like this:

```
@XmlType(name = "SomeType")
@XmlEnum
public enum SomeType {
    @XmlEnumValue("SomeSelfDefineType")
    SOME_SELF_DEFINE_TYPE("SomeSelfDefineType")
}
```

When using XML, it's fine, because it reads the annotation info, but when we use `Json`, `SomeSelfDefineType` will be transfer into `SOME_SELF_DEFINE_TYPE`. Register a lot of custom `Gson serializable/deserializable Interface` to resovle this problem is not a good option for me.

I've checked out other's answers about how to custom some name of field or enum, but I really have a lot of enum definations. Is there any plugin or solutions for me to generate code like this:

```
@XmlType(name = "SomeType")
@XmlEnum
public enum SomeType {
    @XmlEnumValue("SomeSelfDefineType")
    SomeSelfDefineType("SomeSelfDefineType")
}
```

I am not familiar with JAXB or its plugins, could anyone give me some xjb settings or plugin for me to save this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `enum` values using `.xjb` as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"     jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="yours.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings
                node="//xs:simpleType[@name='SomeType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='SomeSelfDefineType']">
                <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SomeSelfDefineType" />
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>

    </jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: hey dude，the problem for me is there are a lot of Enum type for me, so I want to know if there is a easier way to custom all the Enum type.